# Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_BAD_SHARED_USER_ID

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

```
Configuration : Eclipse for Android Developper - jre1.7 - Windows 8 (:s) -
```

I'm developing a small application that lists all the applications present/ installed on the android device. But I am getting the below error while I'm trying to run the code.

```
[2013-03-09 16:10:34 - XXX] Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_BAD_SHARED_USER_ID
[2013-03-09 16:10:34 - XXX] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2013-03-09 16:10:34 - XXX] Launch canceled!
```

Please can any one help me to sort out this error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029207/error-in-xml-parsing

Comment: Are you setting `android:sharedUserId` in your manifest? If so, why?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#uid Astor, Thanks for the link ! @CommonsWare : Indeed, I deleted the shared_user_id field in the Android_manifest.xml and the error disappeared. I'm developping this apllication on Windows and not on Linux this time... Thank you very much!

Comment: @CommonsWare How do I share data between two applications if adding `sharedUserId` causes `INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_BAD_SHARED_USER_ID`? As per the docs `sharedUserId` is required if two apps want to access each other's data

Comment: @Tarun: Use a real IPC mechanism (service, content provider, etc.), secured with a `signature`-level permission.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ok. I was in a view that in order to share content provider sharedUserId is required. If both apps are signed with the same signature I would be able to call content provider of second app.. Right? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Tarun: You are completely incorrect. `android:sharedUserId` **has nothing to do with IPC**. Use the Android permission system (`<permission>`, `<uses-permission>`, `android:permission`, etc.) to secure IPC.

Answer (score 5):

This may be due to your `sharedUserId` value being of a non-permitted value. It has to have the same format as the package structure (e.g. `com.android`).

Comment: Thanks, couldn't find any example of sharedUserId in the docs.